# Guardar response de um get em um objeto e fazer um biding a partir do mesmo. Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, get, vue.js-2

Eu tenho um método GET (não estou usando o Axios) funcionando e gostaria de guardar o resultado dele em um objeto (esse resultado pode ser variado, pois esse GET retorna um objeto com vários outros objetos. Tentei algo como:

gostaria de fazer algo assim no html (separar os produtos por categorias):

```
<b-button 
  class="buttons" 
  variant="primary"
  @click="criaTable(Categoria)"
  v-for="Categoria in produtos.categorias" :key="Categoria" 
>
  {{ Categoria }}
</b-button>
```

e no script:

```
data() {
  return {
    loading: true,
    produtos: [],
  }
},

 mounted() {
  this.getCardapio();
},

methods: {
  getCardapio() {
    const service = new CardapioService();
    service.getCardapio()
    .then(response => response.data)
      .then(data => {
        this.produtos = data;
        return data.data;
      })
       .then(() => this.loading = false)
  }
}
```

um exemplo de retorno desse get:

```
 {
   success: true
   data: [
    0: {
      _id: ...........
      name: Produto X
      price: 10
      image: url
      category: categoria 1
      description: .....
      user: .....
    }
    1: {...}
    2: {...}
    .
    .
    .
    n: {...}
   ]
 }
```

Valeu pela paciência de ler tudo, você é fera!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minha solução foi:

```
    created() {      
      const service = new CardapioService();
      service.getCardapio()
        .then((data) => {
          this.produtos = data.message; 
          console.log(this.produtos);
          this.loading = false;
    })
},
```

armazenei apenas a messagem de retorno para mas poderia ter armazenado todo o body, ou apenas os parametros que eu quisesse, por exemplo: this.produtos = data;

Para fazer o binding é necessário apenas um v-for iterando sobre o objeto => `v-for="produto in produtos"`

Comment: é sério que essa é a resposta? a pergunta manda agrupar e você não faz isso na resposta ??? estranho neh! desculpa mas, muito estranho.